# Как добавить переход по кнопке на следующий контроллер программно? UIButton. Objective-c

Tags: ios, ios7

Нужно по нажатию переходить на следующий контроллер. Как это сделать программно?

Comment: можно посмтреть что у вас уже есть в этом направлении?

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д.

Comment: @Алексей, текст очень желательно вставлять в вопрос как текст.

Comment: Не вижу у вас в коде каких то проблем. а что конкретно происходит по нажатию на кнопку?

Comment: и чтоб два раза не вставать: если в методе поставить брейкпоинт, он сработает?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DetailYV * myNewVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier :@"myNewViewController"];
if (![self.presentedViewController isBeingDismissed]){ //проверить не открыты ли другие VC, если открыты - закрыть их
    [[self presentingViewController] dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}
[self presentViewController:myNewVC animated:YES completion:nil ];
```

где myNewViewController - storyboardID

Comment: Все работает. Но на контроллере в который я перехожу должна быть анимации построения графика. Сам график есть. Но анимации нет.